# Open Edge database connection with php or java

Tags: java, php, database, openedge

We are developing application which fetch data from rest-services and combines it with other data.

Other data source is Procress Open Edge database, but cant connect my clients to database. I'm using PHP and I have tried with JAVA.

Is there any JAR-libraries with Open Edge JDBC or some drivers for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are knowledgebase articles on this:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/21017
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000031743
https://www.progress.com/odbc/resources/tutorials/using-php/connecting-to-a-database-and-executing-sql-with-php

From Java:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19308
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P121595